Use query string parameters on Word add-in SourceLocation(manifest.xml)
I want to use query string parameters on SourceLocation on a Office add in(Word add in). I can add the query string parameters inside the manifest.xml file. How can I read them inside taskpane.html file
The query string parameters I used are stripped and not usable from taskpane.html file.
When I use Window location.search it does not have the query string parameters I added.
Is there any configuration on manifest.xml file or Office to enable query string parameters on SourceLocation

I suspect that is expected behavior, but I'll ask around internally at Microsoft. I can tell you that there's no special manifest markup for enabling query parameters.

Well, the experts say that this should work, so you may have found a bug. Please create an issue on the office-js repo.

It seems like the issue was on my setup. I have override the default source location value. So I needed to modify the overridden location URL as well.
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
              </Action>

<bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?aaa=123"/>
